# Using conkeyrefs in DITA-ot

Tags: dita, oxygenxml

We have a lot of customers and several group of words in customer specific documentation with different suffixes. Sometimes we need to update the words that are included in the customer documentation. To make it easier the words are stored in tables like:

```
<row>
   <entry><ph id="1" customer="A">szolgáltatáshely</ph></entry>
   <entry><ph id="2" customer="A B C D E">szolgáltatási hely</ph></entry>
   <entry><ph id="3" customer="F">felhasználási hely</ph></entry>
</row>
```

The solution is working, however we get a lot of warnings and errors during the validation and gerating PDFs. Is there any better aproach that eliminates these warnings?

Warning message: Duplicate element with ID "some_id" found in the same topic context.

We are using oXygen 14.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually problems like yours appear when in the same DITA topic you have two elements with the same ID like:

```
    <row>
        <entry><ph id="1" audience="A">test1</ph><ph id="1" audience="B">test2</ph></entry>
    </row>
```

Even if your profiling will remove one of the elements and the publishing works, according to the DITA specification it is illegal to have two elements with the same ID in the same topic so both Oxygen and the publishing are correct in reporting the problem.

DITA 1.3 specs:

https://www.oxygenxml.com/dita/1.3/specs/archSpec/base/id.html

```
  The DITA specification requires that all IDs be unique within the context of a topic.
```

If you want to have valid content according to the DITA standard you could try to rewrite your content like:

```
    <row>
        <entry><ph id="1"><ph audience="A">test1</ph><ph audience="B">test2</ph></ph></entry>
    </row>
```

Comment: There is only one problem. We are using toolbar buttons in oXygen in order to help the everyday work of our experts who are not familiar with XML. 

The original XML (in my post) resulted the display of the customer specific value of the id (depending on the profiling attributes) when the reference was inserted to a topic file with the desired toolbar button. 

The solution that you suggested results the display of all the possible values of the the same id, like this: test1 Customer env.[A]test2 Customer env.[B] . It makes harder to understand the displayed content in Oxygen.

Comment: I understand, I will add an internal Oxygen issue to see what we can do about the display. Honestly I also consider confusing your current situation when the end user sees two IDs in the table, each one with a different value. Plus you have invalid DITA content.

Comment: Thank you. Please let me know if you made any progress!